# How can I dissolve the gunked up fertilizer in a Scotts Turfbuilder drop spreader?

Tags: tools

My spreader is gunked up with fertilizer so that the agitator does not spread out the fertilizer and seed anymore. How can I dissolve the fertilizer that is gunked in the agitator so that the spreader will work again?

Answer (score 3):

Warm water trickled over it or applied with a damp cloth normally works, but if the area that the fertilizer is stuck on is hard to get at, a little dissembly may be required.